# Can't enable password protection in Notes app

Tags: ios, password, notes.app

I'm following the advice [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205794) where I want go to settings and set a password. If I do this I get

> **Update Notes**
>   For the configuration of the password protection open "Notes" and update your notes. (*tranlated*)

What should I do here?

iOS 9.3.2 is installed. Also the is no *lock note* option if I tap the *share* button.

Comment: Your iOS device must have version 9.3 of iOS installed. Can you verify this?

Comment: yeah 9.3.2. is installed.

Comment: Mmm what happens if you open Notes, create a new note and then set a password using the Share button? (When you after this go back to Settings > Notes > Password)

Comment: If I tap the share button there is no *lock note* button ..

Comment: Mmm what about reinstalling the Update? Make a backup, and restore your iPhone, or maybe, if you wish, you may try to reset all the settings only, this won't impact your Apps data though

Comment: Oh, just to be sure: did you try to turn it off and on again? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one of my updates I didn't switched to the new *Notes* system, where you can draw and so on (because of incompatibilities). Now I want to switch:

1. Open *Notes* app.
2. Go back to folder
3. Tap the *update* button (on the top left, same height as iCloud)
4. Tap on *update now*
5. It takes some time and you see the number of notes he "converted"
6. Styling is differently. Now you can set your password.

Be careful when updating because there are some incompatibilities (MacBook must have OS X El Capitan, problems with multiple iCloud accounts on the same phone, ...). Don't know why Apple didn't make it work with both versions.